# Is it possible in CiviCRM to change extension of cached php files from .php to something else (e.g. .php_ or .txt)?

Tags: email, scheduled-reminders, smarty, cache

Is it possible in CiviCRM to change extension of cached php files from **.php** to something else (e.g. .php_ or .txt)? Our host (WPEngine) does not allow guest users to write to **php** files on production environment.

We run cron by calling the cron URL from another server using curl, but scheduled reminder emails fail because CiviCRM can't write .php files as guest user (more info: [Scheduled Reminder Email is Empty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15600/scheduled-reminder-email-is-empty)).

Comment: hi, you should try asking this @ http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi michaelmcandrew. Is this not civicrm.stackexchange.com?! The URL starts with: **[http://civicrm.stackexchange.com](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com)** and the logo says **CiviCRM beta**.

Comment: You're in the right place! Welcome to civicrm.stackexchange.com :D

Comment: erm, sorry about that!! yes, you are in the right place :)

Comment: Hi, Soroush, when I do search on WPEngine on stack exchange site I get the impression that hosting on WPEngine is possible but not easy. For example http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7057/in-wordpress-i-want-to-convert-my-installation-from-an-external-database-to-use/.  A valuable comment in this question that WPEngine support says they have some customers running CiviCRM. So you can ask them, what did they do? A hack to change to the extension of the compiled Smarty files or did they relax the permissions?

Comment: Thank you Kainuk for looking into this. Fortunately WP Engine fixed the issue yesterday by adding an exception on the firewall for CiviCRM cron URL.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. The issue is caused by the CachedCiviContainer cache -- which will write a .php file.

A workaround for this is to set the following constant in the civicrm.settings.php file:

```
define('CIVICRM_CONTAINER_CACHE', 'never');
```

Not ideal, as it disables the container cache altogether. But it avoids these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since CiviCRM is software, yes, in theory it could be changed to work differently. The question is always *who* is going to do that work?

You could start the ball rolling by identifying where in the code .php files are being generated, and suggest an alternative way of doing it.

Comment: I just ran into this. The error occurs in symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php when we rename CachedCiviContainer.[HASH].php[hash] to CachedCiviContainer.[HASH].php. The problem occurs with guest users (as the post indicates) -- as WPEngine doesn't allow guest users to write php files. FWIW -- I tried disabling asset caching, but it stills throws errors. WPEngine is a headache to work with -- but it's very popular. May be worth some investigation to see if we can work around that restriction.